# mvc 5 Set Cookie Expire, but expiration back to 01/01/0001

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I set cookie when login success like this :

```
public JsonResult LoginWithPassword(String password)
        {

                Response.Cookies.Remove("Auth");
                string CookieName = "Auth";
                long UserId = 4;

                HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Response.Cookies[CookieName] ?? new HttpCookie(CookieName);
                myCookie.Values["UserId"] = UserId.ToString();
                myCookie.Values["LastVisit"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

                return Json(new { IsSuccess = true, ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, Message = "Login fail, Wrong Password" });
            }
        }
```

and i read it in next page/action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Auth"] == null)
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Access");
            return View();
        }
```

Really strange the cookie of "Auth" always empty. When i check the expiration date in debugging breakpoint, i get expiration date : `01/01/0001`.

why this happend and how to solve this?
This action in two differents controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to implement your code to create cookie. Same code is working fine in MVC5 at my end in firefox browser.
I have used code as below to create cookie -

```
Response.Cookies.Remove("Auth");
                string CookieName = "Auth";
                HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Response.Cookies[CookieName] ?? new HttpCookie(CookieName);

//HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie");

cookie.Value = "Hello Cookie! CreatedOn: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

In addition the check on "Auth" cookie is successful on Index page  as -

public ActionResult Index()

```
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Cookie"] == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        return View();
    }
```

Alternatively I suggest to 
1) Set Expiry after cookie is created in login page  OR
2) add decimal in expiry days eg. 1.0 or 5.0. See article at link -
http://forums.asp.net/t/1982279.aspx?MVC5+Application+Cookie+expires+when+session+ends

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. honestly i found something. if i use breakpoint in action code, the cookie expiration become 01/01/0001 i dont know why this happend. i try delete all breakpoint, app work smoothly